# Microsoft Teams file sharing support for on-premises SharePoint

Tags: file-upload, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-server

We are using Office365 with Microsoft Teams. I need to know whether there is a solution we can use to connect Microsoft Teams groups in order to receive and store files on SharePoint on-premise instead of Online? Is there a connector that can do that? If this is not an option, is there any other chat software that can integrate into SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to your question is **No**.

Microsoft Teams is not available for SharePoint on-premise. It's basically a chat-centered workspace in Office 365.

However it is possible for hybrid environments. Check more details at:

[Microsoft Teams integration with SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198783/microsoft-teams-integration-with-sharepoint-server-2013-enterprise).

Also check below question if it helps you just to show the documents in Microsoft team:

[Microsoft Team integration with on premise SharePoint](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/microsoft-team-integration-with-on-premise-share-point/m-p/210976#)